# How to get user details from another domain

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, active-directory, cross-platform

Currently i am in Domain-A and i am trying to get user id details from another domain(domain-B) with below command.

```
net user user-id /domain
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain domain-A.net.

The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.
```

Since it is failing and trying to find in domain-A itself, So have tried with `net user domain-B\user-id /domain` however no success,  Is there way to get user details from another domain?

Comment: Are these trusted domains and does the Domain-A account which you run it from have access to Domain-B?

Comment: Yes my computer name is connected in Domain-A and the account which we are using from Domain-B.

Comment: Is there a domain trust setup between domain A and B? Is each domain on separate networks/subnets?

Comment: this does not seem to have anything to do with powershell. if not, please REMOVE the powershell tag.

Comment: Yes domain trust setup is there between domain-A and Domain-B. Also both the domain in same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was interested in particular user's domain account password expiry date, through this [Link](http://woshub.com/get-aduser-getting-active-directory-users-data-via-powershell/) able to get details.

**Power shell Command:-**

```
Get-ADUser –Server abc.com username -properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired |ft Name, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires,PasswordExpired
```

Then need to calculate expiry date with below command:-

```
Get-ADUser 'username' -server 'abc.com' -Properties msds-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select Name, @{n='PasswordExpires'; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'msds-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')}}
```